# He “looks like”

Tags: translation, grammar, usage

In my Chinese class we’ve recently had a chapter quiz. I missed the following question:

Translate “He looks like Guan Gong” into Chinese.

My response: 他看关公一样。

Teacher’s correction: 他看**起来像**关公一样。

So my question is why is my response grammatically incorrect?

Both answers translate the same in Google Translate, but why is the “看起来” needed?

Comment: Don't trust google translate.

Comment: user expects google translate to correct wrong Chinese submitted for translation? It seems google is programmed to make a guess as to the intended meaning, and return correct English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V+起来 indicates that V is used as 感官动词(sense verb), like look/smell/sound/taste/feel in English

> He looks like Guan Gong

If you think about it, "He" is not the subject of the action "look", he doesn't look at anything

A clearer example is:

> This flower **looks** beautiful and **smells** sweet

A flower doesn't have eyes and nose, look and smell are sense verbs here, so the translation is:

> 这朵花**看起来**很漂亮, **闻起来**很香

Also, V+上去 is same as V+起来

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the grammar, but the vocabulary.

看 means "look", but only in the sense of "to look at", not "to look like".
像 means "to look like" / "to resemble".

So "He looks like Guan Gong" can be translated as:

> 他像关公。

So why 看起来 ? Maybe the teacher wanted to keep the 看 because that's what you used. 看起来 here is an adverb that means "seemingly" / "seems to".

> 他看起来像关公 He seemingly looks like Guan Gong.

The 一样 is not necessary here, but gives the sentence a nicer rhythm.